# Tab bar menu are not selected in xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode9-beta

I have use the Carbon kit. the tab bar working fine in xcode 8 but in xcode 9 the menu are not selected

[image]

```
 dasboardItems =  [UIImage.init(named: "logo")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),UIImage.init(named: "mess")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), UIImage.init(named: "usericon")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) ]

        carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: dasboardItems as? [Any] , delegate: self)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self, andTargetView: pageView)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(54)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x026B6B)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorColor(UIColor.white)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorHeight(2)
        let tabWidth = self.view.width/3 + 1
        lblChatCounterTrailingConstraints.constant = tabWidth + tabWidth / 2 - 45
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(tabWidth, forSegmentAt: 0)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(tabWidth, forSegmentAt: 1)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(tabWidth, forSegmentAt: 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to update your carbonKit Pod File because carbonKit fixed the bug  for iPhoneX and Xcode 9
 https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit

its work for me.